# How do I create a git repository that contains more than one directory?

Tags: git

I've looked at the answers on stackoverflow that seem to address this but I'm new to git and I find the wording ambiguous when it comes to git repo project branches versus file system directory branches. Or maybe I'm on the right track but can't quite figure out the syntax.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have two paths that are part of a project:

```
  C:\dev\Delphi Library
  C:\dev\Delphi Projects\TNS
```

Both of these paths have multiple sub-directories that need to be tracked. So is it possible for one git repository to track both of these directory branches. I think that the answer is to use git worktree. If it is I cannot figure out the syntax and I'm starting to doubt if worktree is, in fact, the way to do this.

What I've done is create a new repository in C:\Delphi Projects\TNS, stage it, then run

```
git worktree add “C:\dev\Delphi Library”
git worktree add “C:/dev/Delphi Library”
git worktree add “\C\dev\Delphi Library”
git worktree add “C/dev/Delphi Library”
git worktree add "..\..\Delphi Library"
git worktree add "../../Delphi Library"
```

And then all the same without double quotes. Mostly I get the following error:

```
fatal: invalid reference: Library
```

But I also got:

```
fatal: 'Delphi Library' is not a valid branch name.
```

Do I have to initialize a repository in "C:\dev\Delphi Library" first? Should I commit the TNS project first? I've only staged it. Is it even possible to have one repo track multiple non child (can I say "sibling"?) folders? Do I have to specify a branch when running git worktree? The -b options is optional.

Note that there are many other C:\dev folders that I do not want to track so having the git repo in C:\dev is not an option.

I'm trying this with Windows XP using git version 2.8.1.windows.1.

Comment: No, `worktree` is not what you're looking for.  All files that are tracked in a single repository must be in subdirectories of a single directory.  If you only want to track those two folders and not everything in `dev`, you need to create a `Delphi` subfolder and put your repository there.

Comment: I don't want to pretend knowing your project structure better than you do, but I'll just say that if you want these two things in separate directories for development, then that's probably a fairly good sign that you want to have them in separate Git repos as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out worktree is not what you're looking for. Worktree concept is for creating multiple copies of one Git repository.

You should put these project to different Git repositories. However you might realize your idea by using Git submodules. You can set up both directories as Git repository and you can put library project as a submodule under your TNS project. But if you are working on local only (as your question suggests) it might cause more confusion then benefit. Updating, merging and managing submodules sometimes gets complicated, especially between all local repositories.

If you'd like to give a try just initialize both directories as Git repositories and then use below command at `C:\dev\Delphi Projects\TNS`:

```
git submodule add "..\..\Delphi Library" lib
```

This will copy library project under the lib folder inside TNS project. Whenever you edit library project at `C:\dev\Delphi Library` folder, use `git submodule update` from TNS project folder so that changes are transfered to TNS.

If you try to modify submodule folder lib, git will prevent you from pushing your changes to `C:\dev\Delphi Library` folder, since it contains a working copy (not a barren repository).

You can give this solution a try but you are warned, things might get much more complicated when you start to having branches, begin doing rebases etc. At least consider setting up barren remote repositories, so that it would be easier to push changes.

Comment: Well if it creates extra complexity I guess I won't use submodules. I will do as you have all suggested and have separate repositories for TNS and Delphi Libraries. Thank you.